# Arduino to Arduino data transfer via Internet

Tags: arduino-uno, serial-communication, telecommunication, server-communication, arduino-uno-wifi

I'm working on a Project, and want to know-
"How to Transfer Data from one Arduino to another Arduino **via or Over the Internet**...(since I want to transfer data to another Arduino over large distance) ?
Please Help !

Thanks in advance.
-Hardik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1.Use wifi shield or ESP8266 to connect to network.

Step 2. Use any real-time database for data trasfer eg.Firebase.

Step 3. Write database from one device and read from another.